# Check if product exists before saving

Tags: magento2

Hello I have created admin grid for my custom module, I have a form where it is possible to add new product comments. The thing is that I have Product id field, where u can enter id for which product to post comment. So if non-existent id is entered and saved the page breaks.

This is my save controller:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Comments;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magebit\ProductComments\Model\Comments;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Save extends Action
{


    private $productRepository;
    protected $_model;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Comments $model,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_model = $model;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */


    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            /** @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Comments $model */
            $model = $this->_model;

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'productcomments_comments_prepare_save',
                ['comments' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Comment successfully saved'));
                $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the comment'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['comment_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

I was thinking about using productrepository getByID function, but haven't yet figured it out. Hope someone will have answers for me, thanks!

Error:

```
[error] 997#997: *2510 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mageRunCode in /var/www/magento/public/pub/index.php on line 45
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mageRunType in /var/www/magento/public/pub/index.php on line 46" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: magento.test, request: "GET /admin_1c63d9/mui/index/render/key/d4e9ab2bc3f8dae59f5c2d8d7d9c810149e8b2cbe127f209f27a92a316f958ae/?namespace=notification_area&sorting%5Bfield%5D=created_at&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "magento.test", referrer: "http://magento.test/admin_1c63d9/admin_comments/comments/edit/id/24/key/897a6e8fe837ce25195df20fa34bd77ee1be78c70e2e7e2f592f97e33de5fb7f/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code to detect is product exist or not:

```
$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id'); // change to your product id real param name
$productExists = true;
try {
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    $productExists = false;
}
```

**PS:** it requires the product id (from the request). Do not forget to replace the `'product_id` parameter name to the real one you are using in the form.

---

Here is a full code with a modification:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: magebit
 * Date: 18.4.1
 * Time: 16:05
 */

namespace Magebit\ProductComments\Controller\Adminhtml\Comments;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magebit\ProductComments\Model\Comments;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Save extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private   $productRepository;
    protected $_model;

    /**
     * Save constructor.
     *
     * @param Action\Context             $context
     * @param Comments                   $model
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Comments $model,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_model            = $model;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {

            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id'); // change to your product id real param name
            try {
                $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                // In case there is no product: display error message and redirect back
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['comment_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
            }

            /** @var \Magebit\ProductComments\Model\Comments $model */
            $model = $this->_model;

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'productcomments_comments_prepare_save',
                ['comments' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );
            var_dump($productId);
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Comment successfully saved'));
                $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the comment'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['comment_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Before we doing something with a model we try to load corresponding product from the repository. In case there was no product, the `NoSuchEntityException` exception throws and we redirecting the customer to the previous page and displaying the error message, like *"There was no product with id ..."*.

Comment: I couldn't implement it into my code, maybe you can add it to my code?

Comment: @RihardsRepels Sure. Which result is desired when your entity saving with a nonexistent product?

Comment: Well I mean if non-existent product id is inserted first of all it doesn't save it in database and also displays error message.

Comment: @RihardsRepels I've updated my answer. As I understood you editing and saving this model from the grid (listing), so I wrote a redirect back to this page, not to the edit page (because there is no such page for not saved entity). If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: I dont know, after pressing save button, it gives me HTTP ERROR 500. If I understand correctly, parameter name should be the same as field name in ui components file right? `<field name="product_id">`

Comment: @RihardsRepels yes. You can find the error in the web server error log dir, usually, for the apache2 it is `/var/log/apache2/error.log` . Do you have this module somewhere on the web? On the GitHub or something similar?

Comment: https://github.com/repelsins/magento just uploaded my module to github! Also added error to my original post.

Comment: @RihardsRepels Seems this error has not related with the modifications. I'll check your module and send you feedback later.

Comment: ok, i run setup:upgrade, now it works fine when id is correct, but when non-existent - `{"0":"Requested product doesn't exist","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/magento\/public\/app\/code\/Magebit\/ProductComments\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Comments\/Save.php(55): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository->getById('11111')\n#1 \/var\/www\/magento\/public\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107):` this is being saved in var/report

Comment: @RihardsRepels Sorry, its my mistake :) Fixed here https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/magento/commit/e088512bd6f81a90288ddd47a79e94ca03d098cf

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ProductRepositoryInterface::getById($id)` for retrieving the product by id, this will return a `NoSuchEntityException` if there is no product with the given id. Catch that exception and add your custom desired behaviour.

You should use the `ProductRepositoryInterface::save(Product $product)` for saving the product. If you try to save a product with a non-existing id set this will throw a `CouldNotSaveException` you can catch that and add your custom behaviour.

Using `$model->save()` in Magento2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

since using model is deprecated we use this to load with specific field and save data.

we need these 4 classes to load and update or add new data

```
1. `\vendor\module\Model\testFactory $ModeltestFactor`
2. `\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\test $ResourceModelytest
3.`\vendor\module\Model\testRepository $ModelRepositorytest`
4.`\vendor\module\Api\Data\testInterfaceFactory $InterfaceFactorytest`
```

and in class

```
  $model = $this->ModeltestFactor->create();
  $this->ResourceModeltest->load($model,'123456','column_name');

  if ($model->getData()){
      $model->setBinTo('Bin_Code');
  }else {
      $model = $this->InterfaceFactorytest->create();
      $model->setNumber('No');
      $model->setMoveBy('jjjjj');
      $model->setItem('Item_No');
  }

  $this->ModelRepositorytest->save($model);
```

**EDIT**
or you can use only two classes

```
1. `\vendor\module\Model\testFactory $ModeltestFactor`
2. `\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\test $ResourceModelytest
```

and in class

```
  $model = $this->ModeltestFactor->create();
  $this->ResourceModeltest->load($model,'123456','column_name');

  if ($model->getData()){
      $model->setBinTo('Bin_Code');
  }else {
      $model->setNumber('No');
      $model->setMoveBy('jjjjj');
      $model->setItem('Item_No');
  }

  $this->ModelRepositorytest->save($model);
```